# Change Collation on publish database in visual studio 2012

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild

We use Database projects in Visual Studio 2012 and use TFS to build and deploy our solution. We're building two separate web sites which have their own database but the schema is the same. We need to build these databases with different collations, they are deployed for different languages.

We can't find out how to set the collation in e.g. the config.publish.xml file.

Is it possible to set the COLLATION for the database when publishing/deploying?